# Getting Assertion error while reading the PDF file python - pypdf2

Tags: python, pdf, python-3.6, pypdf

I am getting the below error when I try to read a PDF file.

Code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import os

os.chdir("Path to dir")

pdf_document = 'sample.pdf'
pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_document,'rb') #Error here
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/krishna/PycharmProjects/sample/sample.py", line 9, in
pdf = PdfFileReader(filehandle)
File "/home/krishna/PycharmProjects/AI_DRC/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1084, in init
self.read(stream)
File "/home/krishna/PycharmProjects/AI_DRC/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1838, in read
assert start >= last_end
AssertionError
```

NOTE: File is 18 MB in size

Comment: Would be nice if you could indent the error message *as is* from the terminal instead of it being on one straight line.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused Torxed. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: No worries, it's still on a straight line tho :P

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote this and it completely works for me, The pdf is in same folder, you can use os to get a path value of string type too

```
import PyPDF2

pdf_file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("Sample.pdf")#addressing the file, you can use os method it works on that as well

page_content = pdf_file.getPage(0).extractText()# here I get the psge number one(index zero) and then extracted its content

print(page_content)#you can then do whatever you want with it
```

I think the problem with your program is that "rb" thing, you use it in normal file handling, PyPDF2 already has methods called PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter and PdfFileMerger.
Hope it helped
If you counter any problem just mention, and I will try to get back at it.

Comment: Forgot to mention you, this is not a simple PDF. It has diagrams and tables in it. Solution mentioned above is working perfectly for simple PDF's which has only text in it.